# Calculating distances between points in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

I just need some advise about creating a script to calculate the tangential velocity from data. Basically tangential velocity (Vt) = r*W. W is the rotational speed which is 100 rad/s in this case. r is the radius. Therefore, imagine a disk, as you go towards the edge, r increases, therefore the value for Vt increases. My problem is this, behind the spinning disk, i recorded data. The data is in a matrix of 100x100 data points. However, the radius of my disk is 25, i.e, the diameter of my disk takes up the first 25 data points left and right and up and down of the center of the matrix. Is it possible to write a script that can calculate the distance between the center of the disk and a data point. This would give me a value for r. Then multiply that data point by W and it's specific r value?

Regards,
Jer

Comment: Give it a try: [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)!

Answer (score 1):

```
pdist([dpx,dpy;centerx,centery])
```

where dpx and dpy are the coordinates of your data point, and centerx centery those of the center.

```
>>pdist([31,43;50,50])
ans =
20.2485
```